# Sqlite3 column division

Tags: sqlite

I have the following columns (FirstCol, SecondCol, ThirdCol) in a sqlite3 db file:

```
1  Inside   100
1  Outside  200
2  Inside   46  
2  Outside  68
```

First column has type INT, second has type TEXT and third one has type INT.

For each FirstCol value (in this case just 1 and 2) i need to obtain the result of the value associated with Outside/Inside, which is to say 200/100 where FirstCol=1 and 68/46 where FirstCol=2.

I don't mind whether this is done with a single query or by creating a new table, i just need that result.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to look up the values from different rows with [correlated subqueries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery):

```
SELECT FirstCol,
       (SELECT ThirdCol
        FROM MyTable
        WHERE FirstCol = T.FirstCol
          AND SecondCol = 'Outside'
       ) /
       (SELECT ThirdCol
        FROM MyTable
        WHERE FirstCol = T.FirstCol
          AND SecondCol = 'Inside'
       ) AS Result
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT FirstCol
      FROM MyTable) AS T;
```